# JSDoc document final method

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

Is there a way to document a final method in JS using JSDoc.

A final method in Java is one which can't be overridden.

I couldn't find any option in JSDoc website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would seem you can't, since [a search of the JSDoc documentaton for `final`](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=final+site%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fjsdoc.app&t=brave&ia=web) turns up no results.

This isn't all that surprising, because you can't reliably *have* a final method in JavaScript. So if it's important for a method not to be overridden, you'll probably have to resort to documenting that in its description. Still, it would be possible for JSDoc to provide a way to annotate that for tools to pick up on, it just doesn't seem to have it.

Here's an **unreliable** way to have a final method in JavaScript:

```js
class Base {
    constructor() {
        if (this.finalMethod !== Base.prototype.finalMethod) {
            throw new Error(`You must not override 'finalMethod' in your subclass.`);
        }
    }
    
    finalMethod() {
        console.log("This is the pseudo-final method");
    }
}

class Derived extends Base {
    finalMethod() {
        console.log("This is the overridden method");
    }
}

const d = new Derived(); // Throws error
```

But that's easily overcome in any of several ways:

- Wait to create the method until your subclass constructor has already called the superclass constructor.
- Return an object created without using the superclass constructor (for instance, `return Object.assign(Object.create(this), { finalMethod() { /*...*/ } });` (Although now I think of it, that's really just a different way to do #1 above.)
- Return a proxy.
- Create your subclass instances without ever calling the superclass constructor (**not** recommended — but then, none of these are)
- ...probably others...

Comment: Thanks. Since JSDoc actually has many tags for many things that JavaScript don't have, like `@private` (very recent addition to JS) and `@interface` I though there could be an undocumented one for static members too.

Comment: @user5507535 - As I said above, it would indeed be convenient if you could annotate that, but if it's not listed on jsdoc.app I don't think you can.